# How to delete a file/image i have defined in a function

Tags: python, django

In the models.py an uploaded image is renamed and resized to smaller thumbnail versions. In the template i can access those versions by the functions i've defined in the models class. When a new avatar is uploaded i want to delete all of those versions. Any ideas how i could make this work?

models.py

```
def rename_avatar(instance, filename):
    upload_to = 'avatar'
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid4().hex, ext)
    return os.path.join(upload_to, filename)



class Profile(models.Model):    
    avatar =  models.ImageField(upload_to=rename_avatar, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.avatar:

            filename = self.avatar.path
            filename = filename.split('.')[0]

            SIZE = 800, 800
            image = Image.open(self.avatar.path)
            image = image.convert('RGB')
            image = ImageOps.fit(image, SIZE, Image.LANCZOS)
            image.save(f"{filename}.jpg", "JPEG", progressive=True)

            SIZE_medium = 250, 250
            image_md = Image.open(self.avatar.path)
            image_md = image_md.convert('RGB')
            image_md.thumbnail(SIZE_medium, Image.LANCZOS)
            image_md.save(f"{filename}_md.jpg", "JPEG", progressive=True)


    def avatar_md(self):
        filename = self.avatar.url
        filename = filename.split('.')[0]
        return f"{filename}_md.jpg"
```

I've tried something like this, but this doesn't work I only can delete the main image which URL is stored in the DB.

views.py

```
            if new_avatar: 
                    profile.avatar_md.delete(False)
                    profile.avatar.delete(False)
```

Comment: A great tool to remove images from the DB is Django-Cleanup: https://pypi.org/project/django-cleanup/